# Procedural graph rendering optimisation: Draw only visible part?

Tags: java, optimization, graph, rendering

### Background

Let's say I have **millions** of interconnected `Node` instances which together form a graph. Each `Node` has a 2D position. A user has to be able to pan through a procedural render of this graph. Each `Node` has a `draw` method, but if I `draw` all `Node`s every frame, it's very slow.

As the user does not usually want to see the whole graph but instead is zoomed in, the optimisation is in **not drawing the `Node`s that are off screen**.

### My approach

Divide the 2D world space into rectangular `Segment`s. Assign each `Node` to whatever `Segment` they're in. When drawing, find out first which set of `Segment`s the user's view intersects with and `draw` only the `Node`s in those `Segment`s.

### Now for my actual question:

***How do I determine the optimal size of a `Segment`?*** (Make it too big and it's the same thing as drawing everything. Make it too small and there are again too many to iterate through.)

Comment: I think [Quad trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) may be more helpful here than the division into fixed-size rectangles.

Comment: @Alex After looking into it, it indeed seems so. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Quad trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) may be more helpful here than the division into fixed-size rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always determine it by trials-and-errors.
By the way, the size of the segment may depend on the zoom level.

*Another possible solution* is to have two sorted arrays of nodes. One array `Node[] ax` sorted by the `x` position and the other `Node[] ay` by the `y` position.
If you want to display nodes in `(x1, y1) - (x2, y2)`, you will build a set of nodes which are at the intersection of the sorted arrays filtered with the bounds.